# Proper subgroups of $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Reading a book and it said "the group $\Bbb Z_p$, where $p$ is prime, has no proper subgroups." It defines a proper subgroup as a subgroup that isn't the identity subgroup or the whole group. It didn't say the operation; I'm just assuming it's multiplication.

I don't understand why there are no proper subgroups. The example I came up with is $\Bbb Z_{7}$ over multiplication mod 7 and the proper subgroup being $\{6^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ (or just $\{1,6\}$) with multiplication mod 7.

What's wrong with my example? I don't know if I'm misunderstanding what it means to be a subgroup, or if I didn't get the operation right, or something else.

Comment: The operation could not be multiplication because ${\mathbb Z}_p$ does not form a group under multiplication.

Comment: Oh I didn't realise this. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With multiplication, $\mathbb Z_p$ is not a group because the element $0$ has no inverse. However, with addition, $\mathbb Z_p$ is a group, and it has no proper subgroups.

Of course, you can remove $0$ from $\mathbb Z_p$ to get $\mathbb Z_p^*$ which is indeed a group for multiplication, but then the theorem no longer applies. Of course $\mathbb Z_7^*$ has proper subgroups, but that's because it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_6$, and $6$ is not a prime.

Answer (score 3):

The operation is addition mod $n$, not multiplication.

$\Bbb Z_p$ with addition mod $n$ is a group with no proper subgroups.

$\Bbb Z_p^*$ with multiplication mod $n$ is also group, with a much richer structure: it is cyclic and has exactly one subgroup for each divisor of $p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplicatively, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is not a group, since 0 is absorbing. But $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is a group by deleting the zero element. It has order 6 and $\{1,6\}$ is a subgroup.